# How can I find rows that have only 2 _ in them with Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

My current query is:

```
SELECT * FROM "Questions" WHERE "questionText" ~ '[ $][_][$ ]' AND "status" != 'inactive';
```

This returns:

- Jill was shocked to find that she _ none of the answers in the test.
- Brooklyn stood joyously _ her crown proudly _ top _ her head.
- A healthy diet is a _ idea.
- I _ watch a _ movie.

I only want to return items like the second and fourth care with 2 (or more) `_`. I don't want to return multiple `____` next to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
WITH questions (questionText, status) AS (
VALUES
    ('Jill was shocked to find that she _ none of the answers in the test.','active'),
    ('Brooklyn stood joyously _ her crown proudly _ top _ her head','active'),
    ('A healthy diet is a _ idea.','active'),
    ('I _ watch a _ movie.','active')
)

SELECT questionText
FROM questions
WHERE array_length(regexp_split_to_array(questionText,'[ $][_][$ ]'),1) > 2
AND status != 'inactive';
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: @Shamoon `WHERE questionText ~ '(([^_]+|^)_([^_]+|$)){2,}'`